# Showing user information row column wise

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[User Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrRBR.jpg)

I am new to react and using bootstrap to show user information from API. But I want to show per row three users information in separate card which is now showing row-wise. I am not sure how can I do that. My code example is below:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

import User from '../components/cards';

const HomePage = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('some-url-to-get-data')
      .then(res => setUsers(res.data));
  }, [])

  return (
    <ReactBootStrap.Container>
      <ReactBootStrap.Row>
          <ReactBootStrap.Col>
            {users.map(user => (
                <User key={user.username} user={user}/>
            ))}
          </ReactBootStrap.Col>
      </ReactBootStrap.Row>
    </ReactBootStrap.Container>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about exact syntax, but you need to put column inside the loop. It will put all users coulmns on the same row.

```
return (
<ReactBootStrap.Container>
  <ReactBootStrap.Row>
      {users.map(user => (
          <ReactBootStrap.Col>
            <User key={user.username} user={user}/>
          </ReactBootStrap.Col>
        ))}
  </ReactBootStrap.Row>
</ReactBootStrap.Container>
```

)

Comment: hello. thank you for the answer. it fits as much as columns possible but I want to show three columns per row. how do I define column number here? @kost